# Can't save table information to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been working with this code for a whole day but still can't understand where I made a mistake. So basically I want to edit whole mysql table.

I'm easily fetching it, and I need to change some of the data and save it again to the table. But everytime I'm trying to save it - everywhere getting "Array" and nothing more.

It's look like the code is not seeing that I'm making changes there.

Also sometimes when I'm changing bits, only last raw was saving and duplicating everywhere after.

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">

<table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Live</th><th>AQ</th><th>Up</th><th>Down</th><th>Cptch</th><th>VID</th><th>UpOrDo</th><th>UTool</th><th>STool</th></tr><thead><tbody>
<?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            echo "<tr><td><input size='1' name='id[]' value='".$row["ID"]."' readonly></td><td>".$row["Name"]."</td><td>".$row["Live"]."</td><td>".$row["AccQuantity"]."</td><td>".$row["Upvote"]."</td><td>".$row["Downvote"]."</td><td>".$row["Captcha"]."</td><td><input name='VoteID[]' type='text' size='5' value='".$row["VoteID"]."'></td><td><input name='UpOrDown[]' type='text' size='5' value='".$row["UpOrDown"]."'></td><td><input name='UpvoteTool[]' type='text' size='5' value='".$row["UpvoteTool"]."'></td><td><input name='SignupTool[]' type='text' size='5' value='".$row["SignupTool"]."'></td></tr>";
        }

 ?>

</tbody>
</table>
    <input type='submit' name='update' value='UPDATE' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $ID =   $_POST['id'];
    $VoteID     = $_POST['VoteID'];
    $UpOrDown   = $_POST['UpOrDown'];
    $UpvoteTool = $_POST['UpvoteTool'];
    $SignupTool = $_POST['SignupTool'];

    for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
        $user_id = $ID[$i]; 
$sql = "UPDATE Servers SET `VoteID`='".$VoteID."', `UpOrDown`='".$UpOrDown."', `UpvoteTool`='".$UpvoteTool."', `SignupTool`='".$SignupTool."' WHERE `ID`=".$user_id.""; 
      echo $sql."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "getting array" mean? And all you're doing is echoing it out. You're not calling any save method

Comment: I thought the $sql part is the save method? By getting Array I mean, when I'm trying to save I see the sql request looks like this UPDATE Servers SET `VoteID`='Array', `UpOrDown`='Array', `UpvoteTool`='Array', `SignupTool`='Array' WHERE `ID`=2 even though in the input I typed different things

Comment: reverse the code organisation process $_POST data before showing html table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not running the query. Also you are not picking out the data from the array. I would do this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
$user_id = $ID[$i];
$_VoteID = $VoteID[$i];
$_UpOrDown= $UpOrDown[$i]; 
$_UpvoteTool= $UpvoteTool[$i]; 
$_SignupTool= $SignupTool[$i];
$sql = "UPDATE Servers SET `VoteID`='".$_VoteID."', `UpOrDown`='".$_UpOrDown."', `UpvoteTool`='".$_UpvoteTool."', `SignupTool`='".$_SignupTool."' WHERE `ID`=".$user_id."";
mysqli_query($sql);//or whatever way you are runing your query. 
echo $sql."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I guess I have to read more careful the MySQL tutorials next time. Absolutely forgot about the query.